# How to transform an array into a newer one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array like this:

```
    var categories = [
        {
            "info": {"id": 1, "title": "cat1"},
            "products": [{"id": "1a", "title": "prod1"}, {"id": "1b", "title": "prod2"}]
        },
        {
            "info": {"id": 2, "title": "cat2"},
            "products": [{"id": "2a", "title": "prod3"}, {"id": "2b", "title": "prod4"}]
        },
        {
            "info": {"id": 3, "title": "cat3"},
            "products": [{"id": "3a", "title": "prod5"}, {"id": "3b", "title": "prod6"}]
        }
    ]
```

I want to transform this data into like this:

```
var categoriesNew = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "cat1",
            "products": [{"id": "1a", "title": "prod1"}, {"id": "1b", "title": "prod2"}]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "cat2",
            "products": [{"id": "2a", "title": "prod3"}, {"id": "2b", "title": "prod4"}]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "cat3",
            "products": [{"id": "3a", "title": "prod5"}, {"id": "3b", "title": "prod6"}]
        }
    ]
```

I have tried this code:

```
var categoriesNew = []
for(var i=0; i<categories[i].length; i++) {
    categoriesNew.push(categories[i].info)
    categoriesNew.push(categories[i].products)
}
```

But it doesn't provide me my required output. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read the tag description before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_

Comment: You just need to map the array like this: `const categoriesNew = categories.map(({info, products}) => ({...info, products }));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not creating an object.

In your case, the simplest way to create a new object array is a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const newCategories = categories.map(({ info, products }) => ({
  ...info, // spread the info into id and title
  products
}))
console.log(newCategories);
```

```html
<script>
  const categories = [{
      "info": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "cat1"
      },
      "products": [{
        "id": "1a",
        "title": "prod1"
      }, {
        "id": "1b",
        "title": "prod2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "cat2"
      },
      "products": [{
        "id": "2a",
        "title": "prod3"
      }, {
        "id": "2b",
        "title": "prod4"
      }]
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "cat3"
      },
      "products": [{
        "id": "3a",
        "title": "prod5"
      }, {
        "id": "3b",
        "title": "prod6"
      }]
    }
  ]
</script>
```